# Curl extension not working for php 7, Windows 7 and Apache 2.4

Tags: windows, php, curl, php.ini, php-extensions

I've recently upgraded to php 7.1.31, starting from an installation of EasyPhp (Windows 7, x86). After installing the files and configuring the php.ini file, all is running well, except a problem with the curl extension:

`**Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function curl_init()**`

phpinfo() confirms that curl extension is missing.

After a number of verifications and tests:

- This is not a problem of uncommented extension in php.ini (";extension=php_curl.dll" is correctly uncommented).
- libeay32.dll, ssleay32.dll, libssh2.dll are in the right directory at the root of the /php directory (I also tried in the /system32 folder even it is a bad idea, but it doesn't work better)
- php_curl.dll is in the /ext/ directory
- There was no associated error or log found in the Windows Event Viewer
- The windows PATH var contains the /php directory
- The extension_dir path is correctly set in the php.ini file (all others extensions are working)
- I've tried various versions of ssleay32.dll, ssleay32.dll and libssh2.dll, as I supposed one could be broken, but nothing changed.

Maybe an hint: I've checked the list of known extensions with the DOS php command line utility:

`php -r "print_r(get_loaded_extensions())";`

it returns a list of 41 extensions **including** curl and openssl! But, the same command in a php page (Apache 2.4):

`echo "<pre>", print_r(get_loaded_extensions()), "</pre>";`

return a list of 39 extensions, curl and openssl are **missing**.

The underlying php.ini file is the same as the one used for the php CLI and for the web page running with php/apache...

Another point, https://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php refer to libcrypto-.dll
But libcrypto-.dll is not in the default download folder of php (why?). I test without success a libcrypto-.dll

Any idea would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look at the output of `phpinfo();` in both places (command prompt and through a web browser) paying particular attention to the value of the `Loaded Configuration File` value. You did say that they were the same but everything else you've said about the problem indicates that they are not.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem starting PHP 7.3 .

Before (at least on 7.2.3), setting `extension_dir = "ext"` worked fine. But on 7.3.14 or 7.4.2 this does not works.
I had to fully set the path like so :

```
extension_dir = "C:\Program Files\Webserver\bin\PHP\7.4.2\ext"
```

I manage to find the problem by reading the apache error logs